# how to complete install php trader extension

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu-16.04

Hi i am using Virtual box for using ubuntu 16.04 for this project

> https://medium.com/@joeldg/an-advanced-tutorial-a-new-crypto-currency-trading-bot-boilerplate-framework-e777733607ae

i have complete install successfully to composer update
when i type composer update and hit enter i got error
[image]

than i have added `extension=trader.so` to php.ini and checking on phpinfo() its show me
[image]

it showing me installed but still facing same error
help me sorry for my bad english

Comment: It's entirely possible the PHP CLI version (which Composer uses) is different from the one Apache uses. Make sure the extension is installed in the CLI version, you can check with `php -m`

Comment: sid@sidheart:~$ php -m
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
hash
iconv
imagick
intl
json
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_sqlite
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
sockets
SPL
sqlite3
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
xsl
Zend OPcache
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
Zend OPcache

Comment: @ishegg yes i can see there is no trader extension how can i fix this

Comment: So it's not installed. Check where your `php.ini` file is (`Loaded Configuration File` entry of the `php -i` command), and check if the extension is there (and uncomment and all that(

Comment: Wow its Working thank you so much @ishegg You Save my days and life Please Post a Answer than i can check answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The PHP version used by the command line (the one Composer uses) is not necessarily the same used by Apache. The screenshot you attached is showing Apache's version, which appears to have the extension installed. However, if you do

```
php -m
```

you'll see that the extension is not installed in the CLI version. So go to the `php.ini` (you can see where it is in the `Loaded Configuration File` entry for the output of the `php -i` command), and add/uncomment the extension line:

```
extension=trader.so
```

Answer (score 8):

1. **Install trader**: `sudo pecl install trader`
2. Find the correct php.ini by running `php -i | grep ini`
3. **Add the extension to php.ini** by adding following code: `extension=trader.so`
4. **Restart** PHP/Webserver
5. **Check** if trader got installed correctly: `php -m | grep trader`

Answer (score 6):

Enabling the extension is not enough,
 you need to install it on your system,

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php-pear php7.1-dev 
pear install trader
```

Comment: but i am using php 7.1

Comment: No releases available for package "pear.php.net/trader"
install failed

Comment: acording to project tutorial it has pecl install trader command which i successfully install already

Answer (score 3):

The following method can be applied from the command line for many php extensions, still okay php-7.4.

Note, this particular extension **can only be used from php-cli**.

Note, you have to feed >50 OHLCV points before this extension starts to respond, or just fail silently.

```
// Mandatory to install phpize:
sudo apt install php-dev
// This library is required by pecl:
sudo apt install php-xml
// Actual extension compilation from sources:
sudo pecl install trader

// Edit the CLI version of php.ini. (/etc/php/7.4/cli)
// Find php.ini path:
php -i | grep ini
// Declare the extension extension=trader.so
sudo /bin/sh -c 'echo "extension=trader.so" >> /etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini'
```